# How to disable the unlock default keychain at startup?

Tags: networking, password, remote-desktop, vnc

I primarily access my Ubuntu 22 desktop remotely (private LAN, but not physically accessible most of the time)

Once the Ubuntu machine is logged in and keyring unlocked, the RDP / vnc experience is great over 2.5gbe.

But if I want to reboot it, it will start with the 'Unlock default keyring popup, and the machine can't be accessed remotely by RDP or VNC until the keyring is first unlocked. With no way to type remotely of course, I'm dead in the water.

I know there are ways to disabled the default keyring, but I don't want to do that. I still want the usual password protection over sudo etc.

E.g with Macs on my network, I can access them via Screensharing after a fresh reboot. Their keychains are all still locked but I can unlock dialogs remotely as I can always get into the desktop and type passwords as if I were at the keyboard.

Comment: Guess this just isn't possible? Seems really strange to me.